# Estou com o seguinte erro: Requested value "Del" was not found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou migrando um projeto do .NET 4.7 para o .NET 6.0. Estou usando o Visual Studio 2022.

Em uma tela do Windows Forms, apresentava o seguinte erro (com a aplicação rodando e compilada)

> O valor solicitado "Del" não foi encontrado

O estranho é que no .NET 4.7 o projeto funciona, e após migrar para o .NET 6.0 apresenta esse erro.

Debugando o erro se dá nessa linha:
 `this.txtEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.Teste.HtmlEditorControl();`

Aparentemente o erro está no método:

```
public HtmlEditorControl()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     EMPTY_PARAMETER = Missing.Value;
     _defaultBodyBackColor = Color.White;
     _defaultBodyForeColor = Color.Black;
     _defaultBackColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;
     _defaultFont = new HtmlFontProperty(Font);
     _readOnly = false;
     _toolbarVisible = false;
     _toolbarDock = DockStyle.Bottom;
     _bodyText = "";
     _bodyHtml = "";
     _bodyBackColor = _defaultBodyBackColor;
     _bodyForeColor = _defaultBodyForeColor;
     _bodyFont = _defaultFont;
     _scrollBars = DisplayScrollBarOption.Auto;
     _imageDirectory = string.Empty;
     _htmlDirectory = string.Empty;
     _navigateWindow = NavigateActionOption.Default;
     _baseHref = string.Empty;
     _autoWordWrap = true;
     _borderSize = 2;
     stylesheet = null;
     script = null;
     BackColor = _defaultBackColor;
     contextDocumentToolbar.Checked = true;
     contextDocumentScrollbar.Checked = true;
     contextDocumentWordwrap.Checked = true;
     SetBrowserPanelSize();
     BrowserCodeNavigate("about:blank");
     ReadOnly = _readOnly;
     ScrollBars = _scrollBars;
 }
```

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Como voce fez essa atualização? Existe ferramentas que te ajudam com isso. dependendo do tamanho do seu sistema, pode ser uma tarefa bem complicada. [https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0&preserve-view=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0&preserve-view=true)

Comment: @MarcosJunior eu atualizei pelo prompt de comando mesmo - no próprio projeto. O programa está basicamente todo feito, mas em uma tela específica que está com esse erro: " O valor solicitado "Del" não foi encontrado". Esse erro pesquisando na gringa pode ser que algum value do textbox usado na versão 4.7 ao migrar para a 6.0 a tecla Del não está sendo reconhecida... mas é muito vago e ainda não achei a solução....